# Visualize multiple simulations with Drake Visualizer

Tags: drake

Is there a way to run multiple drake simulators at the same time and to see the separate visualizations in different windows?

I'm trying to run multiple simulations in parallel and I wanted to visually double check that everything looks correct. I believe Meshcat would allow for this because you can set different urls, but I'm not sure how to do it with Drake Visualizer

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this isn't currently possible. Rather than targeting a server URL the `drake_visualizer` is just consuming indiscriminately broadcast messages. There are ways in which we could add more targeted broadcasting/consumption.

Why don't you post a Drake issue and when it's resolved, we can put the resolution here as the answer.

Comment: *Maybe* you could try using camera rendering in each sim?  Especially if an image or two was sufficient for you to do your checks?

Comment: xref: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my suggestion from the issue:

If you set the LCM_DEFAULT_URL environment variable to a different value for each (visualizer process, simulator process) pair, the messages will be transmitted on different socket addresses and not interfere with each other.

(For the simulator, you can also set the URL in the DrakeLcm constructor, though the environment variable is often easiest when launching several processes.)

The default value for LCM_DEFAULT_URL is shown here:

drake/lcm/drake_lcm.cc

Line 22 in 20d799e
constexpr const char* const kLcmDefaultUrl = "udpm://239.255.76.67:7667?ttl=0";

Using a different port number, for example, would provide for independent process pairs.

env LCM_DEFAULT_URL=udpm://239.255.76.67:7666?ttl=0 bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer &

or

export LCM_DEFAULT_URL=udpm://239.255.76.67:7666?ttl=0

bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer &

bazel-bin/stuff/my_simulator &